# Decreasing the kernel size

Tags: linux, module, kernel

I successfully compiled the `bzImage` file from source. It came to around `6.0 MB` . Now I am looking to decrease this size.

What components make up this bzImage? I tried using `menuconfig` and removed a few components - but it didn't change the size of bzImage.

I'm targeting `2-2.5 MB` . I used lsmod on my current system and it reported wireless and bluetooth to be taking up a huge chunk.

I do not need these - but how do I remove them; and if I do remove them, would they affect the size of `bzImage` ?

Comment: This is somewhat old at this point, but to get an automatically generated listing of the rough size of various kernel components, you could look in Appendix B of my old master's thesis: http://liu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:473038/FULLTEXT01.pdf. (I can't remember why I spelled it "unessential" instead of "inessential", but I think I had a reason :).)

Comment: Also, anything you compile as modules won't affect the size of the kernel image on disk. Modules are separate from the kernel image.

Comment: So, what goes into the bzImage file?

Comment: Any kernel features you do not compile as modules (i.e., stuff that you compile in), for example. Modules are loaded separately while the kernel is already running. Not everything can be a module either. It wouldn't make sense for basic kernel features.

Comment: How do I find out which features are compiled as modules and which are compiled into the image?

Comment: Modules will be marked `m` in the *menuconfig* interface. You could also look for `CONFIG_FOO=m` in the *.config* file it generates. I can't recall off the top of my head, but I think there's an option to include a list of configuration options that were used when building the kernel image in the kernel image itself too.

Comment: ...and the ones that are marked 'y' are built into the kernel?

Comment: Yup, 'y' stuff goes into the kernel image.

Comment: One reason for the existence of modules is specifically to be able to dynamically load stuff as (if) it's needed, rather than bloat the kernel image with support for everything under the sun.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all the modules on your kernel, and then enable them as you need.
In order to do so, you want to generate the `config` file using the parameter `allnoconfig`, as explained:

```
  allnoconfig     - New config where all options are answered with no
```

Comment: Watch out for `allnoconfig` disabling many things you would want to keep enabled for performance or other reasons if you use it as a base. This includes e.g. swap support and features that work around CPU bugs. I believe its primary use in the kernel is to ensure that the kernel still compiles in a minimal configuration.